# Is Username Globally Unique?

Tags: administration, user, standard-objects, user-management, unique-field

I was under the impression that the `Username` field on the `User` object is globally unique. In other words, even if a value is used in some other instance, that means I cannot create a `User` record with that same value. Whether sandbox or production, an instance is an instance.

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) seems to back up this belief (emphasis mine):

> **Field**
>   Username
>
> **Type**
>   string
>
> **Properties**
>   Create, Filter, Group, idLookup, Sort, Update
>
> **Description**
>   Required. Contains the name that a user enters to log into the API or the user interface. The value for this field must be in the form of an email address. ***It must also be unique across all organizations. If you try to create or update a User with a duplicate value for this field, the operation is rejected.***
>
> Each inserted User also counts as a license. Every organization has a maximum number of licenses. If you attempt to exceed the maximum number of licenses by inserting User records, the create is rejected.

However, today I wanted to quickly create a `User` in our full sandbox, so I exported the record I wanted from our production instance, then inserted it in the sandbox, all using Data Loader. I only realized after I clicked <kbd>Finish</kbd> to fire off the job, that I had forgotten to change the `Username`. I was sure I had set myself back when, to my surprise, the insert succeeded. The two records had the same `Username`, and the operation was allowed.

Was my understanding incorrect? Is it only unique in tandem with the `Organization.IsProduction` value? Is this behavior a bug?

Since Eric deleted his answer, Salesforce itself claims the behavior is [as I expected](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-do-I-receive-an-error-message-Duplicate-Username-1327109140698&type=1) (emphasis mine):

> All Salesforce usernames are unique, for all users, across all Organizations (**including Trial Orgs, Production orgs and Sandboxes**).

Comment: yes it is. Even among portals

Comment: @Eric So...bug?

Comment: Someone recently posted a screenshot of the login prompt with an error message that their username wasn't unique. I think it might have been @daniel-hoechst

Comment: @AdrianLarson - You are speaking about the Salesforce login UserName correct? It could be a bug or I am also misunderstanding it as well. I know in practice I have not been able to set the username to one previously used..

Comment: The `Username` field. Yes, it's the same one you authenticate with. I was really shocked at being able to create a duplicate.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Another point of reference: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Why-do-I-receive-an-error-message-Duplicate-Username-1327109140698&type=1

Comment: @Eric So further evidence that my initial assumption was correct, and the operation *should have failed*.

Comment: yup............Although I am not 100% on the portal/internal uniqueness....As "All Organizations" in ambiguous in the linked document.....Does it include portals in All organization??

Comment: I believe username can be same between production and sandbox instance but in same org we should not have this behavior. So, which user ID you see when you login with duplicate username. Curiosity!

Comment: @Eric That link is answer-worthy imo, since it explicitly states that the distinction between sandbox and production should not break uniqueness. Can't promise I'll accept, but definitely worth an up-vote. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson - can you login with that username? just curious

Comment: @Eric It was for someone else. I'll see if I can repro with my own creds. Hopefully I don't get locked out...

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Oh my, I am not that curious lol

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Salesforce is split across login "domains." Each domain uses its own username index, which means it's entirely possible to create the exact same user on login.salesforce.com, test.salesforce.com, and prerellogin.pre.salesforce.com, and any other unique login domains that may exist. Note that "My Domain" does not constitute a unique login domain; it still participates in the primary login domain. Additionally, portal users in some types of portals can have the same user name in different organizations. So, this means that you can't, for example, have a developer edition org and production org that both use the same username, but you can have the same username in production and *one* of your sandbox orgs. If you try to set the same username in a second sandbox, you'd still get a unique username error.

Comment: So basically we should submit feedback on that document that it is incorrect? Is the documentation *anywhere* aligned with this assessment of platform behavior?

Comment: Well aint that a kick in the pants.....Maybe it is the wording of the doc that is being misread. Maybe it should be "Across all organization of the same domain". Maybe that is what they meant and interpreted it to say

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes. I don't know who wrote that doc, but it's wrong. In fact, I just logged in to one of my sandboxes, and set it to the same username as my primary developer edition org, just to verify that it's still true. It was true 11+ years ago when I started, it's true now.

Comment: I thought I had gotten sandbox test failures because the platform behaved in the manner described, but I guess I was wrong on that.

Comment: @Eric Documentation does occasionally go wrong. It is true that trials and production orgs and DE orgs all share the same login pool, but Sandboxes are not part of that domain.

Comment: Well, I gave the article a thumbs *down* and explained why it's wrong. Excuse me while I go hold my breath waiting for them to fix it.

Comment: As an interesting side note, the uniqueness doesn't appear to be enforced at the database level. @bigassforce created two users with the same username via the Environment Hub. This resulted in a "Your User Name is no longer unique." error on login. See https://twitter.com/bigassforce/status/816332983267430404

Comment: @DanielBallinger Yeah, I did see that. Bugs happen, although I find it oddly specific that there's actually an error message in the system for this condition, like the developers have a bug in a log somewhere because they know it happens...