# Value of sfdcLoginUrl in sfdx-project.json doesn't seem to matter

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode

I'm working on a Salesforce Lightning App project in Visual Studio Code (w/ Salesforce extension), and when I right click on a file and choose "SFDX: Deploy This Source to Org", it deploys just fine - I can check the changes in my sandbox and they show up.

I *thought* that **where this deploys to** is controlled by the value of `sdcLoginUrl` in the sfdx-project.json file. But when I change that value to another sandbox or even something invalid, it still successfully deploys to my sandbox.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Salesforce DX Project Configuration](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_ws_config.htm), the `sfdcLoginUrl` parameter is only for [auth commands](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_auth.htm) within DX when connecting to your orgs.

> **The login URL that the auth commands use**. If not specified, the default is login.salesforce.com. Override the default value if you
> want users to authorize to a specific Salesforce instance. For
> example, if you want to authorize into a sandbox org, set this
> parameter to test.salesforce.com.

**When deploying through the CLI or through clicks within VS Code, it uses the [default org](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/default-org/) set for your project.**

In VS Code, you can change this in several ways:

1. Clicking on the plug icon within the lower left.

[image]

2. Use the config command

`sfdx config:set defaultusername=myusername@name.com`

3. Use the command palette with (`Ctrl+Shift+P`):`SFDX: Set a Default Org`

If you want to change where you're deploying to within a specific command (and not change the default), there's the `--targetusername` or `-u` parameter to pass your username for an org you've already authorized.

`sfdx force:source:deploy -u myusername@name.com...`

---

In terms of "orgs", it just represents salesforce instances you've authorized against (production, multiple sandboxes, scratch orgs, etc). When you authorize, you can provide an `alias` which is considered [best practice](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/sfdx_app_dev/sfdx_app_dev_setup_dx) (see "The Power of Aliasing"). It makes it easier to remember than username.

```
sfdx auth:web:login -r https://test.salesforce.com -a MyDevSandbox
```

Instead of remembering your username for that specific sandbox - you can just remember the alias for the commands (ex. MyDevSandbox).

To see all your orgs you've authorized against, you can run the following:

`sfdx force:org:list`

It'll display your alias, username, and ORG Id.

Comment: So I'm a little confused on what defines an org, or in other words, what's the identifier? I would think it would be a name or url - but from the commands you listed, it seems like it's a username? If so that seems weird, b/c couldn't you have a username associated with more than one org? I think I'm missing something. (btw if I run `sfdx force:config:list` I get a Name/Value/Location of "defaultusername"/"vscodeOrg"/"Local")

Comment: I provided more info in the edit, but usernames are actually [unique](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325728&type=1&mode=1) across your [domain](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154612/is-username-globally-unique). Not to mention, on refresh, each username is appended with your sandbox name. Either way, it's best to give your connection an `alias`. In your example, `vscodeOrg` is an alias you gave your connection when you authorized that org - you can reference it with that alias or use the username of the org as well.

Comment: Ah, now I think I got it - thank you!